# Get application information from .csproj for use in custom health check

Tags: c#, .net, health-check

Is it possible to get data from the `.csproj` file to be passed to a custom health check in a .NET application?

I currently have `endpoints.MapCustomHealthChecks("ApplicationName", "ApplicationVersion");` in my `Program.cs`. It works fine except that I need to make a code update any time I change the version. However both parameters are in my `.csproj` file so I was wondering if it's possible to use these.

Comment: https://edi.wang/post/2018/9/27/get-app-version-net-core ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
var publisherName = Assembly.GetEntryAssembly().GetName().Name;
var publisherVersion = Assembly.GetEntryAssembly().GetName().Version.ToString();
endpoints.MapCustomHealthChecks(publisherName, publisherVersion);
```